# How to loop over select result?

Tags: sql-server, loops

I have this select's  result

[image]

I'm trying to use this code, but I don't have an int id.

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxLAB INT  , 
        lib NVARCHAR(100)
 set @MaxLAB=(select count(LAB_UM) from STARE_LAB_DEMANDE )
WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MaxLAB)
BEGIN
   SELECT lib = LAB_UM
   FROM Mytable WHERE Id = @LoopCounter
 
   PRINT lib  
   SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1        
END
```

I want to loop over this records. The id is `lab_um`.

Comment: Please for god sake, do not add images of code / textual content. Use the code block and add your table there. It makes it easier for possible answerees to evaluate. Thanks. I would also love to see some capitalized letters. This gives a kind of subjective effort-showing impression

Comment: You need to edit the question to show the data/schema you have & what you want as a result.  99.9% of the time manually "looping" in SQL is not the thing to do.

Comment: i want to loop over lab_um field in order to use it inside a stocked procedure  call ,exec myProc @lab_um=

Comment: So in your code you get the count of the records in STARE_LAB_DEMANDE (where LAB_UM is not NULL). Then you set a value equal to that count. Then loop through the records in the table and select LAB_UM. Couldn't you just simplify to `SELECT Lib FROM MyTable WHERE LAB_UM IS NOT NULL`? I don't understand why there is a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through in LAB_UM order easily enough:

```
declare @lib varchar(50)
set @lib=''
while exists(select * from table where lab_um>@lib)
begin
    set @lib=(select min(lab_um) from table where lab_um>@lib)
    /*do stuff here */
end
```

Comment: what do you meau by @labum?

Comment: Sorry I renamed it halfway through and left that one with the wrong name.  I changed it to @lib.